# How to replace rownames data on axis

Tags: r, label

In R progamming I am using the plot function to generate a graph of data. I am struggling with figuring out if I am using the correct method for displaying a mean value onto the visualization.

I want to take a numeric dataset (column of a spreadsheet) and run a mean function on it and place that into a variable.

Example: mean_variable <- mean(table$`numericcolumn`)

I then want to take that variable and print it into a label. Obviously the data is numeric, so I want to have a label to describe what this numeric value is.

Example: label("Average of Data:" mean_variable)

I have tried using several different labeling options.

My first thought since using the plot command and that the X axis is the data axis that the data for the mean, I would use the sub label. For display purposes lets say the value stored in the mean_variable is equal to 5. I tried the following for the sub title:

sub = "Average of Data:" toString(mean_variable))
sub = "Average of Data:" print(mean_variable))

I was expecting either of the above results to be "Average of Data: 5"

I am open to moving this outside of the subtitle if that makes more sense or is easier to manipulate.
I am new to R so im not even sure if I am asking the right question. And as a result getting incorrect answers from searches as a result. I have been attempting to find information on how to display variables in labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to add text annotations to your plot. Nice tutorial on this here: https://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

First, you probably want to use `paste()` to concatenate the label text with the number. It will coerce the `numeric` into a `character` for you.

You can use `mtext()` to put annotations on the margin of the plot. There are arguments to control the position of this text.

You could use `text()` to put the annotations directly into the plot area. There you need to supply the `x` and `y` position of the label and there are also arguments to nudge it if you want to put it next to a specific point rather than on top of.

```r
mean_x <- mean(cars$speed)
mean_y <- mean(cars$dist)
plot(cars)
text(mean_x, mean_y, paste("Average of Data:", mean_x)) # goes in plot area
mtext(paste("Average of Data:", mean_x), side = 1) # goes on margin
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: So i read that exact link to statmethods.net, but I was unable to make heads or tails of the information. Your explaination was perfect. I then reflected on the statmethods link and figured out what they were explaining.  I utilized the mtext method, and was able to place the exact information I was looking for. It almost appears that this text with the positioning is actually a subtitle. Thanks a ton!